# I am having issues creating red and black divs

Tags: icsharpcode

my task is to use loops to display two color div.  I need it to have 12 rows and 8 columns.  and the position needs to be absolute.

I am new at coding so this is a beginning assignment that I would like to learn, but I can't figure out how to do.

This is what I have so far,

```
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){

    }
}
```

Comment: Typo and missing quotes in `redSq.style.position = absoulte;`. In addition, positioning all your divs with absolute will sit them all on top of each other.

Comment: Why did you add j<I?

Comment: @MohammedShafeek It was a typo.

Comment: @j08691 I fixed it, but I was told to do the position absolute. Would you recommend doing it in a different way?

Comment: position: absolute - requires you to calculate the top and left position of each element.
If you instead use display: flex; and set a width to each child, then they will "wrap" correctly

Comment: You can use absolute positioning, but you'll also need to change the placement of the divs are you render them, using either a combination of top/right/bottom/left, padding, margins, etc.

Comment: It's difficult to do if you add each div as absolute..because you need to find and apply top and left position for each div... alternative way is define a wrapper div with 8*35 px width and height auto...and append your div to that wrapper div...and make your inner div's as inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Leyz1jgw/

Solution uses absolute positioning of `<div>`'s.

First, I defined a `gen` function, which creates a square of 35 by 35, at position (`left`, `top`) (top-left corner), and with background color `color`.

```
function gen(color, left, top)  {
    let redSq = document.createElement("div");   // my Div
    redSq.style.position = 'absolute';
    redSq.style.backgroundColor =  color;
    redSq.style.width = "35px" ;  // width
    redSq.style.height = "35px" ; // height
    redSq.style.left = left + 'px';
    redSq.style.top = top + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild(redSq);
}
```

Then, the looping goes like this:
`i` determines the number of rows, `j` the number of columns.
The square in the `i`-th row (`i` is 0-based) will have `i` rows above it.
So, it should be at position `5 + i * (35 + 5)` from the top, since the square has a side of 35 pixels, and the gap is supposed to be 5 pixels (including a starting gap).
Apply a similar logic for the horizontal positioning of the squares.
Now for the coloring: notice that for two consecutive (horizontal or vertical) squares, the colors are supposed to be different, and coincidentally, the sum `i + j` also changes parity accordingly. So color the square according to whether the sum is even or odd.

Here's the looping stuff:

```
for(i = 0; i < 12 ; i++){ //rows
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){ //columns
        let left = 5 + (j * 40); //positioning
        let top = 5 + (i * 40);
        if((i + j) % 2 == 0)  { //coloring
            gen('black', left, top);
        }  else  {
            gen('red', left, top);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a single loop, you can use % modulus to determine if the cell is even/odd to turn it red/black and if its at the end of the row (8 cells) to create a new line.

```js
    
for(var i = 0; i < 64 ; i++){ // foreloop
   
    var redSq = document.createElement("div");   // my Div
    redSq.style.backgroundColor =  (i % 2 == 0) ? "red" : "black";
    redSq.style.width = "35px" ;  // width
    redSq.style.height = "35px" ; // height
    redSq.style.margin = "5px";
    redSq.style.display = "inline-block";
    
    document.body.appendChild(redSq); // making sure the div appears
    
   if((i+1) % 8 == 0){
      document.body.innerHTML += "<br>";
   }
}
```